# Asp.net web api IHttpActionResult springboot Java Equivalent

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-web

hi I am new in springboot and I want to develop rest api in springboot.
In .net web api IHttpActionresult type used to return entity and httpstatuscode in same time,is there any equivalent in spring boot

Comment: Where is your code? What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to edit the status code of your result? Try `ResponseEntity`.

Comment: From now I am in learning status ,I want to map my mind how can I do it, in .net  public IHttpActionResult Myrestcall(){....  return Ok(myresponse)};I just want to learn is there any java equiavelant of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Spring's Class ResponseEntity<T>`. It allows you to add an Object and a Response Status and send to the user.
Example from [ResponseEntity docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html):

```
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders.setLocation(location);
responseHeaders.set("MyResponseHeader", "MyValue");
return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

You see how ResponseEntity accepts the body of the response as its first argument, the headers of the response as the second and the HTTP status as the third.